# How to iterate through result object after querying in mongo DB shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am having a JSON array object something like `[{_id:64,minitem:30},{},{}...]` inside a variable result.. This is the result of an aggregation operation which is a projection of minimum score. I need to iterate over this result and delete the minvales from DB.
I am unable to loop over the result object .. I tried

```
for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){ 
  db.students.update({ 
        '_id': result['_id']
      }, { 
         '$pull': { 'scores': { 'score': result[i]['minitem'] } } 
      }) 
  }
```

This doesnt seem to have an effect. DB is unaltered. I am trying this from `mongo` shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result['result'].forEach(function(doc){
    db.students.update(
        {'_id': doc._id}, 
        {'$pull':{'scores': {'score': doc.minitem }}}
    );
});
```

Uses the forEach function within the Mongo Shell.

Note that after aggregation the documents are actually within a `result` element within the return document currently.

Comment: result['result'].forEach(function(doc){db.students.update( { '_id': result['_id'] },{ '$pull': { 'scores'{'score': result['minitem'] } } })}); I tried this. Im getting an error unexpected token {

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi anytime :)